# Hypothesis to guarantee Lindeberg's condition

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence, measure-concentration, limit-theorems

Imagine to have a set of random variables $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{n}$ independent (**Non** identically distributed). In these scenario, if the Lindeberg's condition hold we can extend the result of the CLT, *i.e.*, calling $\mu_i = \mathbb{E}(X_i)$ , $s_n^2 = \sum_i \left(\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) - \mathbb{E}(X_i)^2\right)$ :
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\mu_i}{s_n} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
(for more details see for example http://shannon.cm.nctu.edu.tw/prob/c27s08.pdf or https://drive.google.com/file/d/1beeTLVbuXEQabqUHReI3K0eJiZ7xfek3/view).

Now even if the set of random variable is not identically distributed, assume that the distribution of $X_i$ respect the CLT hypothesis $\forall i$ (**Hp 1**).

Is this a sufficient hypothesis for the Lindeberg's condition to hold and get the CLT for the set $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{n}$? If yes how could I show it formally, *i.e.* that (**Hp 1**) implies the Lindeberg's condition?

**Follow up question**

Thanks to *Iosif Pinelis* for the nice and clear answer.

Since Lindeberg's condition intuitively guarantees that fluctuations of the random variables from the mean stays "small", I was wondering if assuming finite variances that doesn't grow with $n \rightarrow \infty$, *i.e.* $\textrm{Var} \left( X_n \right) = \mathcal{O} \left( 1 \right)$ (**Hp 2**) would be a sufficient condition to satisfy the Lindeberg condition.

In the example that you proposed (**Hp 2**) is not satisfied since
$$
\textrm{Var} \left( Y_n \right) = (n!)^2 2^{-n} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} (2 \pi n) \left( \frac{n^2}{e^2 2} \right)^n = \mathcal{O} \left( n^{2n+1} \right)
$$

Comment: According to [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131116232910/http://shannon.cm.nctu.edu.tw/prob/c27s08.pdf), your first link hasn't been valid since 2013.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$No, of course the Lindeberg condition is not necessary for the CLT.

E.g., for each natural $i$ let
\begin{equation*}
    X_i:=Z_i+Y_i,
\end{equation*}
where $Z_i\sim N(0,1)$, $P(Y_i=i!)=2^{-i-1}=P(Y_i=-i!)$, $P(Y_i=0)=1-2^{-i}$, and the random variables (r.v.'s) $Z_1,Y_1,Z_2,Y_2,\dots$ are independent.

Then
\begin{equation*}
    \frac1{\sqrt n}\,\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}+\frac{T_n}{\sqrt n},
\end{equation*}
where $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ and $T_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.
For any real $\ep>0$, any natural $k$, and any natural $n\ge k$,
\begin{equation*}
    P\Big(\Big|\frac{T_n}{\sqrt n}\Big|>2\ep\Big)\le P_{1n}+P_{2n},
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
P_{1n}:=P\Big(\Big|\frac{T_k}{\sqrt n}\Big|>\ep\Big),\quad 
P_{2n}:=P\Big(\Big|\frac{T_n-T_k}{\sqrt n}\Big|>\ep\Big). 
\end{equation*}
Clearly, $P_{1n}\to0$ for each $k$ as $n\to\infty$. Also,
\begin{equation*}
    P_{2n}\le\sum_{i>k}P(Y_i\ne0)=\sum_{i>k}2^{-i}=2^{-k}\to0
\end{equation*}
as $k\to\infty$. So, $P\big(\big|\frac{T_n}{\sqrt n}\big|>2\ep\big)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each real $\ep>0$. That is, $\frac{T_n}{\sqrt n}\to0$ in probability and hence in distribution. Also, $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\sim N(0,1)$. Thus, the CLT for the $X_i$'s holds.

On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
    s_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^n EX_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n EZ_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n EY_i^2
    =n+\sum_{i=1}^n (i!)^2 2^{-i}\sim (n!)^2 2^{-n}\to\infty \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$), whereas for each real $\ep>0$ and all large enough $n$ (such that $n!\ge2\ep s_n$) we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    s_{n,\ep}^2&:=\sum_{i=1}^n EX_i^2\,1(|X_i|\ge\ep s_n) \\ 
    &\ge EX_n^2\,1(|X_n|\ge\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   \ge E(Z_n+Y_n)^2\,1(|Y_n|\ge2\ep s_n,|Z_n|\le\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   = E(Z_n^2+Y_n^2)\,1(|Y_n|\ge2\ep s_n)\,1(|Z_n|\le\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   \ge EY_n^2\,1(|Y_n|\ge2\ep s_n)\,1(|Z_n|\le\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   = EY_n^2\,1(|Y_n|\ge2\ep s_n)\,P(|Z_n|\le\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   = (n!)^2 2^{-n}\,P(|Z_n|\le\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   = (n!)^2 2^{-n}\,P(|Z_1|\le\ep s_n) \\ 
    &   \sim (n!)^2 2^{-n}\sim s_n^2, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
by \eqref{1}. Thus, the Lindeberg condition $s_{n,\ep}^2/s_n^2\to0$ fails to hold. $\quad\Box$

---

Then OP additionally asked if there is a counterexample with $s_n^2$ bounded. Here is a simple one: Let $X_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_2=\cdots=X_n=0$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim N(0,1)$, whereas $s_n^2=1$
\begin{equation*}
    s_{n,\ep}^2=EX_1^2\,1(|X_1|\ge\ep s_n)\not\to0
\end{equation*}
for any real $\ep>0$. So, the Lindeberg condition $s_{n,\ep}^2/s_n^2\to0$ fails to hold. $\quad\Box$

---

Now, the positive news. Suppose that we have a triangular array $(X_{nk}\colon n=1,2,\dots,\ k=1,\dots,k_n)$ of independent zero-mean r.v.'s satisfying the normalization condition
\begin{equation}
    s_n^2:=\sum_k EX_{nk}^2\to1, \tag{$*$}\label{0}
\end{equation}
the infinite smallness condition
\begin{equation*}
    \max_{1\le k\le k_n}P(|X_{nk}|\ge\ep)\to0
\end{equation*}
for each real $\ep>0$, and the CLT condition
\begin{equation*}
    S_n:=\sum_k X_{nk}\to Z \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
in distribution, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Then, by Theorem 15 of Chapter IV by [Petrov](https://books.google.com/books?id=zSDqCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), for every real $\ep>0$
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_k P(|X_{nk}|\ge\ep)\to0 \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_k(EY_{nk}^2-E^2Y_{nk})\to1, \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}
where $Y_{nk}:=X_{nk}\,1(|X_{nk}|<\ep)$.

Since the $X_{nk}$'s are zero-mean, for any real $\ep>0$ and any real $M>\ep$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    -EY_{nk}=EX_{nk}\,1(|X_{nk}|\ge\ep)=EX_{nk}\,1(|X_{nk}|\in[\ep,M))+EX_{nk}\,1(|X_{nk}|\ge M),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\sum_k|EX_{nk}\,1(|X_{nk}|\in[\ep,M))|\le \sum_k MP(|X_{nk}|\ge\ep)\to0
\end{equation*}
by \eqref{3},
\begin{equation*}
\sum_k|EX_{nk}\,1(|X_{nk}|\ge M)|\le\frac1M\,\sum_k EX_{nk}^2\to0
\end{equation*}
by \eqref{0} as $M\to\infty$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_k|EY_{nk}|\to0. 
\end{equation*}
Also, $|Y_{nk}|\le\ep$ and hence $E^2Y_{nk}\le\ep|EY_{nk}|$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_k E^2Y_{nk}\to0. 
\end{equation*}
So, by \eqref{4},
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_k EY_{nk}^2\to1. \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}

So, for
\begin{equation*}
    s_{n,\ep}^2:=\sum_k EX_{nk}^2\,1(|X_{nk}|\ge\ep)
\end{equation*}
we get
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{s_{n,\ep}^2}{s_n^2}\sim s_{n,\ep}^2=\sum_k EX_{nk}^2-\sum_k EX_{nk}^2\,1(|X_{nk}|<\ep)
    =\sum_k EX_{nk}^2-\sum_k EY_{nk}^2\to1-1=0,
\end{equation*}
so that the Lindeberg condition $s_{n,\ep}^2/s_n^2\to0$ holds.

Comment: Hi @Iosif Pineli, thanks for your answer, it's pretty clear and well explained. I have then a follow up question since the Lindeberg's condition is only a sufficient condition for the convergence to the standard distribution. If CLT holds for each $X_i$ (as you showed in your example) could this be a (more strict) sufficient condition to get the  convergence to the standard distribution as well? My intuition suggest me that this is the case, is it true?

Comment: @user1172131 : Sorry, I don't understand the question in your comment. In particular, what is "this" in "could this be"? What is "the standard distribution"? Avoid using pronouns such as "this", "that", "it", lacking in specificity.

Comment: @user1172131 : Do you a further response to my answer and comment?

Comment: yes I will formalize better my follow up doubt at the end of the main question as I don't have enough space in the comment box here, thanks again!

Comment: @user1172131 : I have addressed your additional questions as well.

Comment: Thanks @Iosif Pinelis ! There is only one point that is still not clear to me. My finally aim is not to proof that Lindeberg condition (L.C.) holds; I need to proof that L.C. holds to be able to apply the CLT (i.e. Eq. (2) in your answer). Is it possible therefore starting only from the normalization condition  (i.e. Eq. (*) in your answer) and the infinite smallness condition to get the Lindeberg condition (which in turns guarantees also Eq. (2), being a sufficient condition for the latter)?

Comment: @user1172131 : I don't understand your comment. You wrote: "assume that the distribution of $X_i$ respect the CLT hypothesis $\forall i$ (**Hp 1**). [...] could I show it formally, *i.e.* that (**Hp 1**) implies the Lindeberg's condition?". Now what: you want to assume the CLT to get the LC to get CLT (that you assumed)? Anyhow, you cannot get the LC from (*) and the infinite smallness condition. E.g., let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be iid centered Poisson each with parameter $1/n$.

Comment: I want to start from the Hp that each random variable involved in the sum $X_i$ respect the CLT **singularly** (**Hp 1**), i.e. that $\forall i$ if I consider a set of i.i.d. that follows the same distribution of $X_i$ then on this i.i.d. set the CLT is valid. Note that the variables $\{ X_i \}_{1=1}^n$ are not i.d. so I cannot directly claim from (**Hp 1**) that $\frac{S_n}{n} \equiv \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n X_i$ follows the CLT. Then my final aim is to proof that the normalized sum of the set $\{ X_i \}_{1=1}^n$ converge to the normal distribution $Z$ passing through the Lindeberg condition

Comment: Now I understood from your counterexamples that (**Hp 1**) is not enough, but still my objective is to proof that the normalized sum of the set converge to $Z$, so I cannot use this as starting hypothesis. Anyway I'm reading Thm. 15 from chapter 4 of the book you linked (1975 ed.) (Thanks for the ref btw ;) ), and it seems to be able to proof the convergence without using as an hypothesis the Eq. (2) (i.e. CLT condition).

Comment: @user1172131 : I don't feel that I understand your comments well enough to answer them. Apparently, it is not a good idea to be asking additional questions in comments. It is probably better to ask them in separate posts -- which should be prepared very carefully, to be effective both for you and for the answerers.

Comment: sorry for the confusing messages; anyhow your answer was pretty clear and helped me a lot to clarify some points, Thanks!